# Finding Largest value in an array using recursion

Tags: recursion, int, max

This is my test array

```
int [] A = {1,2,7,3,5,6};
```

this is the method

```
public static int largest(int [] A)
{
  int temp = A[0];
  return largestRec(A, 0, A.length - 1, temp);
}

// WRITE THIS METHOD that returns the largest of the elements in A
// that are indexed from low to high.  RECURSIVELY!
private static int largestRec(int [] A, int low, int high, int temp)
{  
  if (low == high)
    return A[low];

  if (low <= A.length){
    if (A[low] > temp){
      temp = A[low];
    }  
    largestRec(A, low+1, high, temp);      
  }   
  return temp
}
```

Why does the tem reset and return `A[0]` which is `1`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not doing anything with the return value of the recursive call to `largestRec`. Remember that parameters are pass by value (even in recursive calls to the same function) so changing it inside the function does not affect the outside.

I don't think you should be passing the `temp` as a parameter at all.

```
private static int largestRec(int [] A, int low, int high )
{ 
  int temp; 
  if (low == high)
    temp = A[low];
  else
  {
    temp = largetstRec( A, low+1, high );
    if (A[low] > temp){
      temp = A[low];
    }  
  }
  return temp;   
}
```

That keeps `temp` local to the function (which I think is what you probably meant be calling it `temp` in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int largestRec(int [] A, int low, int high){  
  var largest = A[low];

  if(low == high)
     return largest;  // or  A[high] because both are same

  for(var i = low; i < high; i++){
    if(largest < A[i])
      largest = A[i];
  } 

  return largest;
}
```

Comment: This needs to be a recursive method so no loops allowed